# Where can I find my current installed brushes for Corel Painter?

Tags: brush, corel-painter

When importing brushes, or creating variants, it's sometimes handy to be able to access the actual files that define the brush. The Program Files entry for Corel Painter (`C:\Program Files\Corel\Painter 2019\Brushes` by default) has the brushes initially installed, but not variants created within the program or within a given Workspace? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I'll periodically need to look up because I've forgotten, but as per [this documentation page](http://product.corel.com/help/Painter/540235477/707000/EN/Doc/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Win&file=Exploring_the_Brush_Controls_palette.html) and [this PainterFactory forum entry](https://painterfactory.com/painter_product_discussion/f/corel-painter-products/27085/purchased-brush-packs-into-painter-2018), the current active brushes for a given workspace are located in the Roaming folder, `Users\(user name)\AppData\Roaming\Corel\(Painter version)\Default\Brushes\`.